# Error 404 Resource Not Found - Power BI / Azure Text Analytics

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-cognitive-services

I've been searching for answers and support regarding deploying Azure Text Analytics through Power BI desktop. Essentially, I've followed the tutorial here for key phrase extraction:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/key-phrase-extraction/tutorials/integrate-power-bi

After following the steps listed Power BI gives me a 404 error code "Resource not found". Others seem to think that the endpoint URL is incorrect, however I triple checked the endpoint URL from my Azure account which is:

https://alextextanalyzer.cognitiveservices.azure.com/

(I'm Alex). My location is set to Australia East. For further reference I've attached my m language edit as well as per the MS instructions. [M editor code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZtag.jpg)

Does anyone have any recommendations as to why this might be occurring? I've already changed the privacy settings as per the instructions, and still get an error. As far as I know I've done everything else correctly?

Error code is as follows:

An error occurred in the ‘’ query. DataSource.Error: Web.Contents failed to get contents from 'https://alextextanalyzer.cognitiveservices.azure.com/v3.0/keyPhrases' (404): Resource Not Found
Details:
DataSourceKind=Web
DataSourcePath=https://alextextanalyzer.cognitiveservices.azure.com/v3.0/keyPhrases
Url=https://alextextanalyzer.cognitiveservices.azure.com/v3.0/keyPhrases

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a part of your endpoint.

The provided documentation says:

```
endpoint = "https://<your-custom-subdomain>.cognitiveservices.azure.com/text/analytics" & "/v3.0/keyPhrases"
```

Based on the capture you provided, you forgot the "text/analytics" part. It should be "https://alextextanalyzer.cognitiveservices.azure.com/text/analytics/v3.0/keyPhrases"

Can you check?

And please, rotate your API key as it is well visible in the capture ;)